# Constrained when choosing X, Y and X+Y distributions

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Let's say I want to "create"/"think of" 3 random variables:
X, Y, X+Y.

P(X=0) = a

P(X=1) = b

P(Y=0) = c

P(Y=1) = d

P(X+Y=0) = e

P(X+Y=1) = f

P(X+Y=2) = g

a+b=1, c+d=1, e+f+g=1

Then:

E[X] = b and E[Y] = d and E[X+Y]=f+2*g

Am I constrained to choose b,d,f,g such that b+d=f+2*g, because the linearity of the mean (expected value)? Isn't this weird? I thought there should be no link between the distribution of X,Y and X+Y...

Comment: ??? Since $X+Y$ obviously is completely determined by $X$ and $Y$, could you elaborate on what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I want to give values to a,b,c,d,e,f,g such that there are no contradictions. So, what are the conditions I have to satisfy?

Comment: Since if you assume independence, $a,b,c,d$ completely determine the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, they completely determine the distribution of $X+Y$, which gives $e,f,g$. Otherwise, you need to consider the joint distribution of $X,Y$. In effect, you seem to be asking (albeit in a strange way) how to compute the [sum of two Bernoulli distributions.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bernoulli+sum)

Comment: I don't assume independence. So, yes, I need the joint distribution. But in the joint distribution there are the values e, g and 2 values whose sum is f. So, when considering the joint distribution, I should care about the relation b+d=f+2*g, right?

Comment: You might find it useful to parameterize the joint distribution in terms of a single additional probability, such as $h=\Pr(X=1,\,Y=1)$.  The numbers $b,d,h$, with the condition $h\le \min(b,d)$ (plus some comparable conditions on the remaining three possibilities), determine any such joint distribution.  Therefore they completely determine $e,f,$ and $g$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The main problem was that I started with X and Y. I should have started with the joint distribution and from that to infer the probabilities for X and Y.